# why does this main function does nothing?

Tags: python, function

I see this strange python function

```
@click.group()
def main():
    pass
```

It is the main entrance function, but why does it do nothing?

Comment: Culd you give some more context?

Comment: well `pass` does nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a function is decorated with [`@click.group`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/#click.group), a [`Group`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/#click.Group) is created, and can later be used to add subcommands, e.g.:

```
@click.group()
def main():
    pass

@main.command()
def sub():
    print('I am a subcommand')
```

The group function doesn't have to do anything itself, if you don't need additional logic or default logic without a subcommand.